# Default File Name when printing from Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf

When printing a web page using a pdf printer (saving the page as pdf), Chrome and Firefox both use the pages `<title>` attribute for the default file name. However, Internet Explorer uses the pages `URL`.

Is there a way to change this functionality in Internet Explorer so that I can control the file name?

**NOTE:** I am not talking about showing the `URL` on the Header/Footer of the page, but the file name when attempting to save to your local system.

Comment: Looks like the default file name comes from the PDF printer, not from the browser. At least in FF43, there's no default name at all, when trying to print this page (with PDF Complete), but IE shows the URL.